# sharepoint item tracking field removal

Tags: list, sharepoint-online

I have created a SharePoint item tracking object which I would like to use for some internal tracking however there are some fields that I would like removed when creating a new item. I cannot see an obvious way to delete them.

Below is the list view and I would like to remove Category and Related Issues

[Detailed List View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DyH8.png)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify: do you want the fields removed ONLY when creating a new item (and have them filled in later when editing the item) or do you want them gone for good in the list? The first requires programming but the second can be done in the user interface under the "List Settings" for the list.

Comment: Hello, I would like to remove it for good in the list.